# css will not load from a file

Tags: css, apache, debian

I cannot load .css from a separate file.

For example if I have html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href "style.css" rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css">

<head>

</head>

<body>

<h1>My CSS web page!</h1>
<p>Hello world! This is a W3Schools.com example.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The css does not load

however if I have css within the same html file the css loads properly. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Changed HTML To code below as suggested by several people. Still has not effect. sytle.css is in the same directory as my source html.

```
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>My CSS web page!</h1>
<p>Hello world! This is a W3Schools.com example.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

css style sheet:

```
<style>
    body
    {
        background-color:#b0c4de;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Possible typo: Missing `=` for `href` attribute.

Comment: Also you might want to move that tag into the `head` section.

Comment: Probably you are not linking to where the style.css file actually is.  The way you have it linked now, the HTML file is looking for a file called style.css that is in the same folder level as itself.

If you have say a folder called Project, then both your HTML file and CSS file need to be in that folder.

You also are missing an "=" for your href attribute.

Comment: With the last change It will be working...
If css don't apply it will be caused by a wrong formated css file. 
Can you paste the css file contents?

Comment: and please don't use w3schools.com: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 3):

Your `link` tag is malformed and should be in the `head` (as opposed to the root of the document):

```
<link href "style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Should be (notice the `href=` correction):

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Need to lose the spaces before and after the = on type=""

Comment: @Michael No you don't, whitespace doesn't matter there.

Comment: Oh, in either case, probably best to promote consistency though?

Comment: @Michael On those grounds, I give you the win. (:

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css">
```